# How to set Anchor to Popover in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

I have a Popover in Material-UI from which I want to permanently set the anchor to a button. Not only on click with `event.currentTarget`.
How can I do this with typescript?

Unfortunately, the current examples in Material-UI use `event.currentTarget` and with a reference it is not working.

```
import React,{useRef} from 'react';
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    typography: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  }),
);

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const ref = useRef(null)


  return (
    <div>
      <Button ref={ref}  variant="contained" color="primary">
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        open
        anchorEl={ref}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Typography className={classes.typography}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-anchor-ff6gr?file=/demo.tsx:0-999) a codesandbox for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must have missed some detail. I followed the [Simple Popover example in official docs](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#simple-popover) and it still works.

If you want to use `useRef`, make sure to refer to `buttonRef.current` when setting `anchorRef`

Below is the forked codesandbox:

[image: Edit Popover Anchor]

Comment: It works with event.currentTarget. My question is how to permanently set the anchorEl to the button without event.currentTarget.

Comment: thanks! Do you know, why when I change `open={open}` to `open`, it is not referencing the anchor anymore?
https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-anchor-5xdon?file=/demo.tsx:935-946

Comment: @Jöcker yeah, first, when the component is mounted, `buttonRef.current` is `null` so that you also set the prop `anchorRef` directly to null , before the `buttonRef` is referenced to `<Button>`, resulted in your unwanted behavior. To avoid that, use useEffect to listen to `buttonRef`'s changes. Here is the forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-anchor-586yo?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: I suggest making the `useEffect` note more prominent - saved me some headache but down here in the comments I almost missed it

Answer (score 3):

2 things

- you need to store the state of opened popup
- open it from the outside
- close it from the inside

relevant **JS**:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    typography: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  })
);

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const [popOverVisible, setPopOverVisible] = useState(false);
  const togglePopOver = () => {
    popOverVisible === false
      ? setPopOverVisible(true)
      : setPopOverVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        ref={ref}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={togglePopOver}
      >
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      Status: {popOverVisible.toString()}
      <Popover
        open={popOverVisible}
        anchorEl={ref}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Button
          ref={ref}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={togglePopOver}
        >
          CLOSE Popover
        </Button>
        <Typography className={classes.typography}>
          The content of the Popover.
        </Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**: upon the user's comment below:

```
      <Popover
    open={popOverVisible}
    anchorEl={ref}
    anchorReference="anchorPosition"
    anchorPosition={{ top: 50, left: 140 }}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "left"
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "left"
    }}
  >
```

forked [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-anchor-wloes?file=/demo.tsx:0-1563)

Comment: The Popover should be in the top-bottom corner of the button. With ref, it appears in the middle of the screen...

Comment: @Jöcker, added `anchorReference="anchorPosition"` & `anchorPosition={{ top: 50, left: 140 }}` to get you what youre looking for